# Rails HABTM Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails

and first of all thank you for reading my question.

I'm fairly new to Rails, and have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship set up in my application. A *business has and belongs to many categories*, and a *category has and belongs to many businesses*.

How might I go about **creating a drop down selection menu for the categories inside of the businesses/new.html.rb form?** I can't seem to figure out how I associate the two when creating a new business. I'm sure it's something simple. Please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the collection_select tag. I have a multiple select box setup in on of my applications code is below. In your example, simply replace `annoucement` with `business`.

```
<%= collection_select 'announcement', 'category_ids',
        Category.all, :id, :name, 
        { :include_blank => 'None'}, 
        { :multiple => true, 
          :name =>'announcement[category_ids][]',
          :selected => 0 } %>
```

edit: You can remove `:multiple => true` if you don't want to have a multiple select.

The `:selected => 0` sets the selected element on load to the first item in the list, which I am setting as `'None'` using `{:include_blank => 'None'}`

Comment: Wow sir, thank you very much. A gentleman and a scholar you are indeed. I searched for this answer for HOURS. Again, my thanks.